# How to move attribute line in Visio 2013 Crow's Foot Diagram

Tags: microsoft-visio-2013

I am working on creating a crow's foot database diagram in Visio 2013.

From this [example from Microsoft](https://blogs.office.com/2012/10/24/database-notations-tap-the-full-power-of-visio/), the line separating the attribute name on the BankAccount entity and the type fits nicely. The attribute data type does not wrap lines.

[image: Microsoft example showing crow's foot diagram attributes]

When I do this the data type name wraps around. When I attempt to move the line it shows as "locked".

[image: Crow's foot diagram with locked line attributes]

Does anyone know how to move the attribute line so that data type names fit on a single line like the Microsoft example?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The attribute line is moved via a yellow diamond control handle at the bottom of the Entity shape, with the caption Locate Type Divider. You have accidently selected a sub-shape. Just click on the page and pack onto the Entity shape.
[image: Moving the type divider line]